# graduated rules with fill color for text

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, fill

[image]

On an exercise with graduated rules, I tried to reduce the white boxes for the negative numbers, I would like the white rectangles to be smaller like for the positive ones but it is like the minus sign puts the limit of the rectangle everywhere on each corner, even where it is not, so here on the right side. I have no clue on how to reduce such a box o_0 ... :-(

here is my code for this part :

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%mathématiques - fichier numérique de tous mes exercices
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %pour le symbole n°
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % pour les listes avec \enumitem : à inclure si on utilise 
\usepackage{enumitem}

% spécification des marges, taille papier
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\geometry{hscale=0.85,vscale=0.85,centering}
%\usepackage{fullpage} % une autre solution, pas testée

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{} 
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\raggedright\mbox{\frakfamily\fraklines\yinipar{S}}}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
% fin de la définition des marges

\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% le package qui pemet de définir des unités et leur affichage
\usepackage{siunitx} % Alignement des valeurs etc.
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
    round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}

\usepackage{xcolor} % pour les couleurs sur les règles graduées par exemple
\definecolor{shamrockgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
\definecolor{rose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.5}
\definecolor{richlavender}{rgb}{0.67, 0.38, 0.8}
\definecolor{tangelo}{rgb}{0.98, 0.3, 0.0}

%----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\noindent MATH\'EMATIQUES
\newline
\vspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{cursive}Un exemple de repère:\end{cursive}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (0,0) node[below left]{$O$};
        \draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[dashed] (-1.1,0) -- (-0.4,0);
        \draw (1,0) node[below]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.4) -- (0,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,-0.8)-- (0,-0.4);
        \draw (0,1) node[left]{$y$};
        \draw [dashed] (1,0) -- (2.4,0);
        \draw [dashed] (0,1) -- (0,2.4);
        \draw [dashed] (2,2) -- (2,0) node[below] {$2$};
        \draw [dashed] (2,2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$2$};
        \fill [red] (2,2) node[above=2mm,right]{$\alpha(2,2)$} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{cursive}Exercice \no 12 p29:\end{cursive}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item les abscisses des points sont en bleu:

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
            \draw[->] [thick](-0.68,0) -- (0.13,0);
            \draw[step=0.01][very thin, gray] (-0.68,-0.06) grid (0.13,0.06);
    %le point M
            \draw (-0.6,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$M$};
            \draw (-0.6,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.6,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,6\phantom{-}$};
            \draw (-0.5,0) node {$|$};
    %le point N
            \draw (-0.4,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$N$};
            \draw (-0.4,0) node [below=5pt]{$-0,4\phantom{-}$};
            \draw (-0.4,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.3,0) node [below=5pt]{$-0,3\phantom{-}$};
            \draw (-0.3,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.2,0) node {$|$};
    %le point 0
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$O$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,1\phantom{-}$};
            \draw (0,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node [below=5pt]{$0$};
    %le point P
            \draw (0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$P$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$0,1$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\item les points S et T :

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
            \draw[->] [thick](-0.22,0) -- (0.78,0);
            \draw[step=0.01][very thin, gray] (-0.22,-0.06) grid (0.78,0.06);
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$O$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node [below=5pt]{$0$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$P$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [below=5pt]{$0,1$};
    %le point T
            \draw (-0.16,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$T$};
            \draw (-0.16,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.16,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,16\phantom{-}$};
    %le point S
            \draw (0.7,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$S$};
            \draw (0.7,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.7,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$0,7$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that have `\phantom{-}` inside each of these nodes: `{$-0,6\phantom{-}$}`. This asks LaTeX to leave a space the size of the `_` character after the number, which is why you have the extra space after the negative numbers. If you take the `\phantom` commands out then you get:

[image]

**EDIT**

To further adjust the positioning of the labels so that the comma lines with up the marker on the axis you can load the [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZ) `positioning` library and use positioning commands on the nodes like `below left=5pt and -12pt` -- here the `5pt` adjusts the distance that the node label appears below the coordinate and the `-18pt` adjusts the distance to the left. In this way, with some  trial and error to find appropriate adjustments, you can obtain:

[image]

Here is your code cut down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item les abscisses des points sont en bleu:

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
            \draw[->] [thick](-0.68,0) -- (0.13,0);
            \draw[step=0.01][very thin, gray] (-0.68,-0.06) grid (0.13,0.06);
    %le point M
            \draw (-0.6,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$M$};
            \draw (-0.6,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.6,0) node [below left=5pt and -12pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,6$};
            \draw (-0.5,0) node {$|$};
    %le point N
            \draw (-0.4,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$N$};
            \draw (-0.4,0) node [below left=5pt and -12pt]{$-0,4$};
            \draw (-0.4,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.3,0) node [below left=5pt and -12pt]{$-0,3$};
            \draw (-0.3,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.2,0) node {$|$};
    %le point 0
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$O$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [below left=5pt and -12pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,1$};
            \draw (0,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node [below=5pt]{$0$};
    %le point P
            \draw (0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$P$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$0,1$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\item les points S et T :

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
            \draw[->] [thick](-0.22,0) -- (0.78,0);
            \draw[step=0.01][very thin, gray] (-0.22,-0.06) grid (0.78,0.06);
            \draw (-0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$O$};
            \draw (-0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0,0) node [below=5pt]{$0$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$P$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.1,0) node [below=5pt]{$0,1$};
    %le point T
            \draw (-0.16,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$T$};
            \draw (-0.16,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (-0.16,0) node [below left=5pt and -18pt, blue,fill=white]{$-0,16$};
    %le point S
            \draw (0.7,0) node [above=5pt, red,fill=white]{$S$};
            \draw (0.7,0) node {$|$};
            \draw (0.7,0) node [below=5pt, blue,fill=white]{$0,7$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i understood your solution but i put the `phantom` to have a center on the numbers not on the numbers *PLUS* the minus sign. i would like that the |absolute value| of numbers on the graduated rules are positioning just below the `$|$` mark. but indeed you are right the phantom created an invisible character on the white filled box. i  thought it will be truly invisible, even for the box ... my bad.

Comment: i dont find any neat way to reduce the white area...

Comment: @FannyMae See my edit

Comment: thank you vm for this improvement.